# How to disabling auto embed in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, youtube, embed

I need to put a youtube playlist in a href, belong the code I'm using :

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88KroShLWEg&list=RD-8wU-LnDrxc&index=27&spfreload=1" target="_blank">here</a>
```

but the link is automatically embed in my post page, what should I do to display something like that : ' [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88KroShLWEg&list=RD-8wU-LnDrxc&index=27&spfreload=1) (with youtube playlist urls ):

Comment: That shouldn't be happening...Are you pasting the link in the "Visual" view of the WYSIWYG? Or are you in the "Text" tab?

Comment: Hello, I'm adding this in the text tab

Answer (score 2):

WordPress automatically adds a filter to embed the videos. All you have to do is removing this filter with the following line (in a plugin or in the `functions.php` file of your theme): `remove_filter('the_content', array($GLOBALS['wp_embed'], 'autoembed'), 8);`.

([source](http://wpengineer.com/2487/disable-oembed-wordpress/))

Comment: Hello, I have tried this but the video is still embedded

Comment: Just tested with your example, it works for me (I obtain the `here` link). Are you sure you don't have any plugin that adds a similar filter?

Comment: I just tested it as well, and got the *here* link. Something funky is going on on your wp

Comment: I mean the OP's wp, not yours, @Jeremy